Did the prophet eat meat sacrificed in the name of Allah by quraysh?
A few years ago, a local ahlul hadith khateeb said, animals butchered by pagans with sole intention of selling its meat is permissible to muslims. I didn't ask for proofs from him. Now I am trying to find out the reason for his view. A relevant report in this regard is found in Bukhari.

Allah's Apostle presented a dish of meat (that had been offered to him by the pagans) to Zaid bin 'Amr, but Zaid refused to eat of it and then said (to the pagans), "I do not eat of what you slaughter on your stonealtars (Ansabs) nor do I eat except that on which Allah's Name has been mentioned on slaughtering."

Few points to be noted from above report.

The quraysh kept giving meat to prophet time and again.

They gave meat sacrificed for sake of Allah also.

The incident is before revelation of quran.


Based on the above points can it be construed that the prophet ate meat sacrificed in the name of Allah by quraysh? Another point to be considered while answering is the udiyah by pagan quraysh during hajj before 610 CE

It is not permissible to eat anything which is slaughtered by anyone other than a Muslim or a Kitabee. Even if a pagan says the name of Allah in order to sell it to a Muslim he does not do so as an act of worship and he does not believe in Allah and lacks intention hence his act is not accepted by Allah and his slaughtered meat is not halal.
The Quran limits the people whose slaughtered meat can be eaten:

وطعام الذين أوتوا الكتاب حل لكم
the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you
— Quran 5:5
فدل بمفهومه - مفهوم المخالفة - على أن طعام من عداهم من أهل الأديان لا يحل
By implication it indicates that the food of those other than them from the followers of other religions is not halal
— Tafsir Ibn Kathir


وإن كان الذابح من المشركين عباد الأوثان ومن في حكمهم ممن سوى المجوس وأهل الكتاب - فقد أجمع المسلمون على تحريم ذبائحهم، سواء ذكروا اسم الله عليها أم لا، ودل قوله تعالى: {وطعام الذين أوتوا الكتاب حل لكم} بمفهومه على تحريم ذبائح غيرهم من الكفار، وإلا لما كان لتخصيصهم بالذكر في سياق الحكم بالحل فائدة
If the slaughterer is a Mushrik  idol worshipper or the like, apart from Magians and People of the Book, Muslim scholars unanimously held that the animals they slaughter are prohibited, whether they pronounce the Name of Allah upon slaughtering them or not.
Allah (Exalted be He) says:

The food (slaughtered cattle, eatable animals) of the people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians) is lawful to you

This Ayah implies that slaughtered animals of the disbelievers other than the People of the Book are unlawful; otherwise there is no point in mentioning People of the Book exclusively in this ruling.
— Fataawa al-Lajnah ad-Daa’imah


The hadith you are asking about is as follows:

أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لقي زيد بن عمرو بن نفيل بأسفل بلدح، قبل أن ينزل على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم الوحى فقدمت إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم سفرة، فأبى أن يأكل منها ثم قال زيد إني لست آكل مما تذبحون على أنصابكم، ولا آكل إلا ما ذكر اسم الله عليه
The Prophet (ﷺ) met Zaid bin 'Amr bin Nufail in the bottom of (the valley of) Baldah before any Divine Inspiration came to the Prophet. A meal was presented to the Prophet (ﷺ) but he refused to eat from it. (Then it was presented to Zaid) then Zaid said, "I do not eat anything which you slaughter in the name of your stone idols. I eat none but those things on which Allah's Name has been mentioned at the time of slaughtering."
— Bukhari

In this version at least there is no clear indication that the Prophet ﷺ ate anything that the pagans gave him. There is also no clear indication that the pagans mentioned the name of Allah alone on it rather the implication is that it was slaughtered on stone idols and without mentioning the name of Allah since this is the reason for refusal given by Zaid. Hence arguing anything from it is wrong.
Even if we accept that the Prophet ﷺ ate from it  then this incident is from the time before the start of revelation and hence it is abrogated and not usable for  jurisprudence. Just like one can no longer drink wine, marry idolator women, attach our names to adopted sons, pray for forgiveness of deceased disbelievers etc. because these have been forbidden in later texts. It is possible that the Prophet ﷺ in his early years ate whatever meat was available as long as that did not constitute shirk as the laws of Shariah had not been revealed yet. There is no evidence that he ate the meat slaughtered by pagans after the revelation of the laws.

I am not at all suggesting the prophet ate meat sacrificed for idols. The incident only points to the thing that quraysh sacrificed in the name of Allah and ghayrullah, they gave both kinds of meat to prophet. Prophet refused to eat meat sacrificed in the name of ghayrullah

Your comment is not relevant to my answer.
